# How to remove white space between two images

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an .aspx page with two images that are the full width of the page.

The issue is that there is white space between the two images that I do not want.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<img src="Images/NavBar.png"/>
<img src="Images/ImageHeader.png"  />
</div>
</form>
```

How do I remove the white space?

I am not using any CSS at the moment, but would if needed.

*Edit*
This is the CSS that resolved:

```
img {margin-top: -4px }
```

Greg

Comment: When you say that you are not using any CSS, does that mean you are not allowed to or that you are not currently?

Comment: Not current, I would if necessary.

Comment: try using negative margin-top attribute on the images after the first

Comment: In HTML, line breaks count as a space. Try putting the two `<img>` tags in sequence without line breaks between them.

Comment: @Havenard, I tried this, but it still showed the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with below css

```
div, img {
  margin: 0;
}

div { 
  padding: 0; 
}
```

**Updated**

```
img {margin-top: -4px }
```

Comment: I cant believe this is till an issue!
in Firefox 35.0.1 (most up to date right now) I needed `margin-top: -5px`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the space in between the 2  tag, it'll remove the gap. there is no need to add any margin or padding on img.